# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 | Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Im facing a an issue while Im adding a method to the controller class with @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) annotation. The issue is when I add this method and start application. Application unable to load resources (css,JS etc). On the browser I get:
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) 
and on the Run logs I get this message:
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported

When I remove this method from the controller class, all works fine. Dont know why is this happening. Im sure its nothing to do with Configuration or resources in Dispatcher Servlet mapping because without this method every thing works perfectly fine.

I need to use this method because of some business requirement, which otherwise is not possible.

Can any body help me in Identifying where the issue is.

```
@Controller
public class InvoiceController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {
        String username;
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        username = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
        username.toUpperCase();
        // Logic to build menue based on the Role of the user.
        HashMap hm = new HashMap();
        OrderItems od = new OrderItems();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("usr", username);
        //Set the object for Menue Links on the Page
        model.addObject("mnue", hm);
        model.setViewName("index");
        model.addObject("odi",od);
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("Im here in Genaric Post Method");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please also note that Im using Spring Security configurations. Is there anything to do with Security? Or there is some issue with Controller Class configuration.

Thanks in advance for your anticipation.

Regards,

D Kamran

Answer (score 0):

Add endpoint url value to request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

This happens because Post method declared mapped to all paths as both Method and Controller class don't have that value

Comment: Its already there. /index is working perfectly fine. Issue is with only the other method. As I remove other method things start working good. What is the issue with the other method?

Comment: It seems that you did not read my answer correctly. If you declare a Controller class and a method without RequestMapping value attribute, spring will map all paths to this class and method. You have added "/index" to GET method. Add "/index" or any other value to POST method

Comment: Got your point. Issue is I want a generic method that should not bind to any particular path. Reason I want to create a multi step wizard style application and on each post call of page I will then add logic inside this method to handle request. Is there any way we can do that?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can remove @RequestMapping annotation if you are not going to use this method for POST. But if do need POST then you also need path.

Comment: Thanks and what about If I add @RequestMapping annotation at class  level with some absolute path and then use that procedure. I think this will work?

Comment: yes it will. As you have provided some base path for POST method. But this path will be applied to GET method also. So if you specify "/abc" as your path at Class level, then GET method or "/index" will become "/abc/index" and POST method will be mapped to "/abc"

Comment: After adding Requestmapping at Class level now .css and .js are loading for all pages except those that are served/rendered by the class containing requestmapping at Class level. Im getting this error

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ccb/invoice/webjars/adminlte/2.3.3/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

in Browser console Im getting HTTP 404 error. Dont know whats wrong. All static resources mapping in Servlet mapping file is correct.